# change directory for tesseract in mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

i m trying to run :

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open("sample1.jpg")

test = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')

print(text)
```

and am recieving this on my mac :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 170, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhishekagarwal/Desktop/OCR_testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    test = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

i probably found a windows solution to change the dir: please tell me its equivalent on mac.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

plus i have tried all other reinstalling homebrew, xcode, sudo stuff.

Comment: Huh? That solution also works on Mac. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried specfying it in the python script.. is there another place to put it??

Comment: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py'

Comment: [edit] that into your question, please.